# fill datagrad manually from foreach loop

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I wrote a MySQL wrapper to obtain certain information from a database. How can I tabularly display my results? I'll be llooping through the results of the query and add it to the datagrid, but how? Must be something like this

```
grid.Add(value1, value2, ...)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, you will want to bind your datagrid (in XAML) to an ObservableCollection (in code behind or in the viewmodel) using the datagrid's ItemsSource property.  Then you can add items to the ObservableCollection and they will show up in the DataGrid, or remove them and they will disappear.  If you need specific help, post some code that would allow us to help further...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I want to have 3 columns of strings. In an array `data` these data is stored. So I'd loop through it by foreach and add it to the observable collection?

Comment: You can add the items in ObservableCollection, set that ObservableCollection as ItemsSource to the DataGrid.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340710(v=vs.100).aspx refer here to know more.